# Can't select default value of pickerView

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have a pickerView in which there are a lot of subjects. Every subject is a class like this:

```
class subjects {
    var idSubject: String = "";
    var nameSubject: String = "";
    var notesSubject: String = "";
    var colorSubject: String = "";

    init(subjectId: String, subjectName: String, subjectNotes: String, subjectColor: String) {
        idSubject = subjectId
        nameSubject = subjectName
        notesSubject = subjectNotes
        colorSubject = subjectColor
    }

    func printSubject(){
        print(idSubject," - ",nameSubject," - ",notesSubject," - ",colorSubject)
    } 
}
```

I set my pickerView in this way:

```
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}

public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return MenuViewController.subjectsArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return MenuViewController.subjectsArray[row].nameSubject
}
```

I want to select the row of a particular subject, but I can't because with `indexOf` it "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(subjects) throws -> Bool'" in this lines of code:

```
if let index = MenuViewController.subjectsArray.indexOf("Matematica") {
    self.subjectsMenu.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What's the type of `subjectsArray` array? is it an array of `subjects` (`[subjects]`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if let index = MenuViewController.subjectsArray.index(where: {
    $0.nameSubject == "Matematica"
}) {
    self.subjectsMenu.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: instead of YourSubjectType what do I have to write?

Comment: @Marco `YourSubjectType` means the type name that represents the subject. For your question it means `subjects`

Comment: For such a case, there is no need to cast it if you mention as a closure parameter, you could use it as is; Check my answer to make it more clear to you :)

Comment: @AhmadF Yes right, i edited my answer and removed cast

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [index(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689674-index), the appropriate method for such a case is [index(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688966-index):

> Returns the first index in which an element of the collection
>   **satisfies the given predicate**.

Which is applicable because you have an array of custom object (`subjects`), as follows:

```
if let index = MenuViewController.subjectsArray.index(where: { (subjectsObject) -> Bool in
    subjectsObject.nameSubject == "Matematica"
}) {
    print("found the desired index: \(index)")
    self.subjectsMenu.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}
```

---

*Additional remarks:*

- the name of your custom class should be *"Subject"* instead of *"subjects"*. Usually, the name of the classes refers to a singular object, with [upper camel case](http://wiki.c2.com/?UpperCamelCase).
- When comparing strings: `subjectsObject.nameSubject == "Matematica"`, it would be better to *trim* it and compare its *lower/upper* case version of it, as follows:

  `subjectsObject.nameSubject.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) == "Matematica".lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)`